# How to edit profile summary of an ERC20 token. on etherscan test networks?

Tags: ethereum, etherscan

I created an ERC20 token using solidity and truffle , and deployed it to ROPSTEN ,
Now it's visible on etherscan ropsten ,
I want to edit the profile summary but the options don't appear ( although i verified the bytecode )
Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update token profile on mainnet, you should submit a application to etherscan, to verify your project.

[mainet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZya8.png)

As my experience, testnet explorer is not supported to update token info